# Qt Creator crashes on creating or opening .ui files. How can it be diagnosed?

Tags: c++, qt

Suddenly my Qt Creator started crashing when I try to open or create .ui file.

I've already tried complete uninstall and reinstall with no effect.

Where can I look for some logs to understand what is happening?

Windows 10
Qt Creator 4.14.1
Qt 5.15.2
MinGW 8.1.0
CMake 3.19.2

Comment: Try to open it in standalone designer. Maybe you add another designer-plugin?

Comment: Designer just won't launch, seems to be the issue. I don't use any plugins and it is clean install. Most probably it's some corrupted temporary or settings files that persist through uninstall, but I have no idea where to look for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It was corrupted templates.xml file in $HOME/.designer/ directory.